# Transportation of bacteria

Tags: bacteriology

I would like to take an apparatus containing bacteria to another country (Bolivia) from the U.S.. How do I determine whether I am allowed to do this?

The bacteria are:
http://www.atcc.org/Products/All/49787.aspx,
http://www.atcc.org/Products/All/53774.aspx,
http://www.atcc.org/Products/All/51573.aspx,
http://www.atcc.org/Products/All/700550.aspx

Also... What is the best way of transporting bacteria from one country to another?

Comment: there are some regulations w.r.t pathogenic strains.. you have to get a certificate issued that says that the sample that you are carrying is non-pathogenic non-hazardous etc

Comment: @WYSIWYG Can you give me the contact information of someone who could help me with that?

Comment: it depends on the laws of different governments. Ask someone in the customs.

Comment: Please go through this link http://www.dehs.umn.edu/bio_pracprin_std_ship_guide.htm and this pdf ( www.ncsu.edu/ehs/dot/Bio_shipping.pdf ). Since all of the microbes are Biosafety level 1, you shouldn't have much problems.

Comment: @okarin  That's actually bad advise.  I would actually recommend that you ship them ahead of yourself.  Not al microbes are Biosafety level 1, and their BSL level is not actually what is considered (risk level by CDC in the US, IATA has set standards as well).  You need to determine if your bacteria are UN2814, UN2900, or UN3373.  IF they are not pathogenic (not just to humans, but animals) but are GMO then they will be UN3245. Remember dry ice by itself is considered a hazardous material.  Post specifically what you're moving and I'll give you an answer.

Comment: @TheLastWord That's a good link to what needs to be covered, but your later comment is not entirely correct, and might cause confusion as BSL is not directly correlated with [Risk Group Classification](http://www.cdc.gov/biosafety/publications/bmbl5/BMBL5_sect_II.pdf)

Comment: @AtlLED What do you mean by post specifically what you're moving? Is there information that you need other than the names of the bacteria?

Comment: @okarin names of the bacteria, are they GMO (transformed with a plasmid counts unfortunately), the transport media, and transport temp.  Ie. NEB 10b's transformed with HIV-env in a glycerol stock transported on dry-ice.